# Спрятать блок при, когда проскролили сайт в самый низ (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Есть такой скриптик:

```
jQuery.fn.fadeElements = function (a) {
    $(this).hover(function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).fadeTo(a.inTime, a.inOpacity);
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).delay(a.delayTime).fadeTo(a.outTime, a.outOpacity);
    });
};
$(function () {
    $('#ubar').fadeElements({
        inOpacity: 1,
        outOpacity: 0.1,
        inTime: 200,
        outTime: 200,
        delayTime: 1000
    });
});
```

Как сделать, чтобы если мы проскролили сайт до самого низа, то блок с #ubar плавно исчезал, т.е. display: none, но при этом, чтобы не спорил со скриптом выше, который плавно показывает и прячет блок при наводке на него?

Comment: А с какой вообще радости он должен, как вы сказали, "спорить"? Или с сегодняшнего дня отменили возможность вешать на объект несколько событий?

Comment: Ну ок. А как сделать, что бы при "ударе" об низ сайт блоку применялось display: none плавно, ну а когда отрываемся, то снова display: block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите [пример решения задачи](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/zbQbB/)

```
$.fn.fadeElements = function(a){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo(a.inTime,a.inOpacity);
    },function(){
        $(this).stop(true,true).delay(a.delayTime).fadeTo(a.outTime,a.outOpacity);
    });
};
$('#ubar').fadeElements({
    inOpacity:1,
    outOpacity:0.3,
    inTime:200,
    outTime:200,
    delayTime:1000
});
/* -- */
var currentScrollTop = 0;
var dH = parseInt($(document).height() - $(window).height(),10);
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(dH <= currentScrollTop){
        $('#ubar').fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
        $('#ubar').fadeIn(1000);
    }        
});
```

Comment: никакой реакции. В css надо что-нить прописывать?

Comment: Что значит никакой реакции? Я вам живой пример кинул. По ссылке смотрите

Comment: Превосходня реакция!

Comment: @inferus-vv, мелькнула мысль, что вы весь код в dom-ready не обернули. Все, что я написал, поместите между следующим кодом:

    $(function () {
    
       // тут весь код
    
    });

Comment: Да, ты прав. Моя самая частая ошибка. А почему когда кручу вверх, то блок появляется не сразу. Т.е. колесико надо прокрутить вверх на 2 шага, только тогда появится

Comment: Попробуй проявлять fadeIn() без duration